# Find the eigenvectors of $ A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 2 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} $.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Find the eigenvectors of
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 2 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}.
$$
I know you can solve $ \det(A - \lambda I) = 0 $ to find the eigenvalues of $ A $, but I keep getting no free variables. However, I thought this was impossible, but I know this problem works.

Comment: The characteristic polynomial is $\det(XI-A)=X^2-X-2$. What do you mean by "no free variables"?

Answer (score 0):

$$
A-\lambda I=  \left[\begin{matrix}0 - \lambda &2  \\1 & 1-\lambda\end{matrix}\right]
$$
so your equation is
$$
(0-\lambda)(1-\lambda) - 2\times 1 = 0
$$
giving
$$
\lambda^2 - \lambda -2 =0
$$
or
$$
(\lambda +1)(\lambda-2)=0
$$
(thanks to @graydad for spotting an error)

Comment: thx! i'd blame the late hour, but it's just a typical malfunction. got excited by all the minus signs ;-)

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I forgot about the identity matrix.

Comment: do you understand how that comes about?

Comment: Yes, just to subtract \lambda from the item that's in both the nth column and row of A.

Comment: the importance of eigenvectors rests on their close connection with the invariant subspaces. an eigenvector may be stretched or contracted, but the 1-dimensional subspace it defines is unchanged by the transformation. if you write out the equations corresponding to the shorthand $Mv=\lambda v$, beginning with: $m_{11}v_1+\cdots =\lambda v_1$ then bring the RHS variables over to the LHS, you will see why lambda is subtracted from the main diagonal. we then require that the set of (homogeneous) linear equations have a non-trivial solution. this only happens if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue

Answer (score 0):

If you solve for the eigenvalues you should get $\lambda = -1,2$. Now use these values to solve the equation $A\mathbf{v} = \lambda \mathbf{v}$ for $\mathbf{v}=\left[\begin{matrix}v_1  \\v_2 \end{matrix}\right]$. For example in the case of $\lambda = -1$ we want to solve $$A\mathbf{v} = - \mathbf{v} \\ \implies  \left[\begin{matrix}0&2  \\1 & 1\end{matrix}\right] \left[\begin{matrix}v_1  \\v_2 \end{matrix}\right] = \left[\begin{matrix}-v_1  \\-v_2 \end{matrix}\right]$$ Completing the matrix multiplication on the left yields a set of two equations. Namely, $$\begin{align}2v_2 = -v_1 \\ v_1+v_2 = -v_2\end{align}$$ Since any scalar multiple of a vector is still the same vector, we have some free reign in choosing $v_1$ and $v_2$, so long as the two equations above are satisfied for the pair of numbers chosen. I recommend sticking with integers for eigenvector entries. It makes the vector easier to plot ($v_2=1$ makes for an integer $v_1$) Once you have your pair you have one eigenvector. Repeat the process using $\lambda = 2$ to get your second eigenvector.